# I want to change my Geo json file to Topo json format cause of size

Tags: javascript, json, geospatial

is there any tool to install that will work for me Here it is my code given below

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"PS-130"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":
[[
[67.274635,24.790281],[67.299156,24.782957],[67.324593,24.775660],[67.324921,24.773165],[67.329575,24.771231],[67.335503,24.771635],[67.345261,24.779057],[67.350258,24.779848],[67.364525,24.777601],[67.375496,24.783390],[67.380539,24.782928],[67.390610,24.776785],[67.391059,24.776721],[67.396591,24.775936],[67.397621,24.776450],[67.400177,24.777723],[67.408577,24.779249],[67.423676,24.773058],[67.428223,24.773623],[67.443901,24.781853],[67.443763,24.783324],[67.443631,24.784732],[67.441480,24.807670],[67.438881,24.838857],[67.449277,24.841456],[67.484363,24.821314],[67.512302,24.799873],[67.547388,24.789477],[67.579875,24.790126],[67.579875,24.801917],[67.579875,24.817416],[67.566881,24.848603],[67.545439,24.884989],[67.531145,24.911628],[67.526597,24.928522],[67.520749,24.955811],[67.521389,24.979482],[67.518800,24.979851],[67.514251,25.018186],[67.496708,25.060419],[67.457074,25.093556],[67.427836,25.109150],[67.383003,25.131891],[67.337521,25.150084],[67.290740,25.166328],[67.271248,25.181921],[67.273197,25.198165],[67.282293,25.226104],[67.307633,25.260540],[67.328425,25.276134],[67.329075,25.296276],[67.345968,25.307322],[67.360262,25.305373],[67.377156,25.357352],[67.393399,25.407382],[67.403795,25.433372],[67.415491,25.453514],[67.399897,25.492498],[67.397298,25.528234],[67.392100,25.563970],[67.397298,25.589960],[67.388851,25.617899],[67.381054,25.642589],[67.323934,25.642589],[67.323812,25.642035],[67.304084,25.597844],[67.296587,25.585217],[67.280015,25.576932],[67.263838,25.574170],[67.259103,25.563516],[67.254368,25.544182],[67.248450,25.526427],[67.235823,25.514985],[67.222014,25.512617],[67.210966,25.505120],[67.195578,25.489338],[67.186897,25.469609],[67.174665,25.462507],[67.162039,25.452643],[67.162434,25.416343],[67.165590,25.400560],[67.164012,25.391090],[67.153359,25.371362],[67.143889,25.361892],[67.138365,25.336246],[67.140428,25.313902],[67.140733,25.310599],[67.134814,25.303102],[67.115086,25.270747],[67.095793,25.249218],[67.093257,25.246388],[67.087861,25.240366],[67.101667,25.237441],[67.108092,25.237441],[67.120941,25.236727],[67.117371,25.230302],[67.116658,25.223878],[67.118085,25.216739],[67.125937,25.208173],[67.135217,25.203890],[67.138073,25.196752],[67.119513,25.188900],[67.103095,25.181048],[67.088104,25.175337],[67.073827,25.170340],[67.070972,25.158919],[67.070258,25.142500],[67.085963,25.116802],[67.094529,25.104667],[67.110947,25.088962],[67.133076,25.089676],[67.145211,25.093959],[67.157346,25.103953],[67.166626,25.112519],[67.174478,25.116802],[67.178762,25.118230],[67.182331,25.123227],[67.189469,25.124654],[67.200177,25.123940],[67.211598,25.116088],[67.217309,25.108950],[67.225161,25.101098],[67.231586,25.093959],[67.238010,25.084679],[67.243007,25.075399],[67.245148,25.058267],[67.238724,25.048274],[67.228730,25.038994],[67.220878,25.026145],[67.211598,25.019720],[67.202260,25.009358],[67.240094,24.981161],[67.258654,24.973666],[67.255798,24.962958],[67.251515,24.950466],[67.234383,24.929765],[67.248004,24.923352],[67.260853,24.923352],[67.280127,24.929776],[67.287265,24.937629],[67.302256,24.949764],[67.315818,24.962613],[67.328668,24.971179],[67.327240,24.961899],[67.322957,24.942626],[67.322957,24.934059],[67.322957,24.919783],[67.321529,24.912644],[67.310108,24.909789],[67.300114,24.909789],[67.295117,24.909789],[67.289406,24.906220],[67.283696,24.900509],[67.276557,24.896940],[67.262281,24.889802],[67.252287,24.884805],[67.239438,24.881235],[67.238724,24.886946],[67.242293,24.892657],[67.241579,24.898368],[67.228666,24.904161],[67.224746,24.889790],[67.216537,24.873372],[67.221735,24.867431],[67.228084,24.861372],[67.231058,24.859290],[67.238792,24.858100],[67.247417,24.855721],[67.260504,24.854531],[67.270320,24.853341],[67.275673,24.850367],[67.277458,24.845013],[67.277458,24.837280],[67.276566,24.829844],[67.276566,24.820326],[67.275971,24.811106],[67.274781,24.800993],[67.272996,24.796234],[67.274635,24.790281]
]] }}
]}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)?

Comment: this tutorial is not full filling my requirement.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure that tool is exactly what you want. Read the wiki https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki and use the tools in the tutorial mentioned by Lars Katthoff such as ogr2ogr.

Answer (score 1):

**In linux:**

Open terminal, go to the folder in which geojson file is there and type below code (change, the file names):

topojson file.geojson -o file.json -p

- -p is used to retain the properties element from geojson file. If you don't want properties, then you can omit -p.